# Get the current browser version in Protractor test

Tags: google-chrome, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to get the browser version in Protractor using this code:

```
let actualCapabilities = await browser.getCapabilities();
console.log("Browser Name: " + actualCapabilities.get('browserName'));
console.log("Browser Version: " + actualCapabilities.get('browserVersion'));
```

For Firefox it works fine:

```
Browser Name: firefox
Browser Version: 62.0
```

But for Chrome it shows undefined in the browser version:

```
Browser Name: chrome
Browser Version: undefined
```

Is this not possible for Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

For me works this one:

```
onPrepare: async () => {
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    const capabilities = await browser.getCapabilities();
    console.log(capabilities.get('version'));
```

it could be helpful to look at entire capabilities Map Object and find what you need:

```
onPrepare: async () => {
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    const capabilities = await browser.getCapabilities();
    console.log(capabilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, there is the solution. Then for **Chrome** we should use

```
actualCapabilities.get('version')
```

and for **Firefox**

```
actualCapabilities.get('browserVersion')
```